# Alert Dialog only with the image

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I have to show an image once the game is over. For this I am using a Alert Dialog and using the zoom animation. As of now i could get it wilt the alert dialog with the boundaries set with black color. I need only the image without any of the background. Please advice me with the change needed in my code

```
public void showDialogGameOver() {      

    showToast("Game Over ! ");  
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.dialoggameover, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);     

    alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create(); 
    alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimationZoom;
    alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false); 
    alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new 
               ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    alertDialog.show();  
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
public class MyCustomDialog extends Dialog {

    public MyCustomDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.alert);
        setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));        
    }
}
```

Reference :

1. [Extend Dialog Class Example](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/02/13/extend-dialog-class-write-its-button-click-activity-interfaces-android/)
2. [Dialog Fragment with Transparency](http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2013/09/custom-dialogfragmnet-example-in-android.html)

Comment: Thanks Chintan,I added your code. Still no success. I have edited my question with the snapshot of my device screen

Comment: @iappmaker i edited my answer. Please  check it again and try it. :)